# How to convert py2neo.database.cursor class to a dictionary or list in python?

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Using graph.run() py2neo v3 to connect to neo4j DB: How can I convert an instance of py2neo.database.Cursor class to a dictionary or list in python?

Was simple in py2neo v2 using py2neo.cypher.core.RecordList class which is what graph.cypher.execute() the equivalent to graph.run would have returned if using the previous version...

Comment: Have you tried iterating over it?

Comment: cast to a list  as Christoph Willemsen suggested & then iterate over that as you advise... works great! (I was stuck because I couldn't figure what to iterate over)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could do with the `data` method:

http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Cursor.data

This is designed for use with libraries like Pandas where you need to extract the entire result.

Comment: New link to the data method: https://py2neo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database/work.html?highlight=cursor.data#py2neo.database.work.Cursor.data

Comment: @Nigel Small, 404 on the provided link

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Nigel Small, you can use the [`.data()` method](https://py2neo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database/work.html?highlight=cursor.data#py2neo.database.work.Cursor.data) to convert it into a list.

Here is how it works,
 let's take for example this line of code calling `graph.run`, whose result is saved into `tags` variable:

```
tags = graph.run(query)
```

the result is a **py2neo.database.Cursor class** (containing a dictionary):

```
 tags
-------------------------------
 ['py2neo', 'python', 'neo4j']
```

And by applying the `.data()` method, it becomes:

```
tags = graph.run(query).data()
```

whose result is a **list** (containing a dictionary):

```
[{'tags': ['py2neo', 'python', 'neo4j']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast it to a list :

```
result = session.run("MATCH (n) RETURN n")
records = list(result)
```